# ORDER BY certain string at the bottom then alphabetical by a different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to order a query and am not getting the desired results:

```
SELECT R.[Name] AS Project, ISNULL(P.[Name]+' - '+P.[Description], 'KanBan') AS Sprint, S.[Number] AS Story, T.[Name] AS Task,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 1 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Monday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 2 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Tuesday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 3 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Wednesday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 4 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Thursday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 5 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Friday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 6 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Saturday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 7 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Sunday
FROM DailyTaskHours D
INNER JOIN Task T ON D.TaskId = T.PK_Task 
INNER JOIN Story S ON T.StoryId = S.PK_Story 
LEFT JOIN Sprint P ON S.SprintId = P.PK_Sprint 
INNER JOIN Product R ON S.ProductId = R.PK_Product
GROUP BY R.[Name], P.[Name], P.[Description], S.[Number], T.[Name]
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (P.[Name]+' - '+P.[Description]) = 'KanBan' then 1 else 0 end, Project ASC, Story ASC, Task ASC
```

First, I want where ever P.[Name]+' - '+P.[Description] is NULL and is filled with 'KanBan' to go to the bottom after than I want it in alphabetical order by Product, then Sprint after product, then story then task.

How can I acomplish this?

Edit: Thanks all here is the final query:

```
SELECT R.[Name] AS Project, ISNULL(P.[Name]+' - '+P.[Description], 'KanBan') AS Sprint, S.[Number] AS Story, T.[Name] AS Task,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 1 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Monday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 2 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Tuesday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 3 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Wednesday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 4 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Thursday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 5 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Friday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 6 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Saturday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 7 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Sunday
FROM DailyTaskHours D
INNER JOIN Task T ON D.TaskId = T.PK_Task 
INNER JOIN Story S ON T.StoryId = S.PK_Story 
LEFT JOIN Sprint P ON S.SprintId = P.PK_Sprint 
INNER JOIN Product R ON S.ProductId = R.PK_Product
GROUP BY R.[Name], P.[Name], P.[Description], S.[Number], T.[Name]
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNULL(P.[Name]+' - '+P.[Description], 'KanBan') = 'KanBan'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END,
    Project ASC,
    Sprint ASC,
    Story ASC,
    Task ASC
```

Comment: `P.[Name]+' - '+P.[Description])` can never equal `'KanBan'`... For one thing "KanBan" doesn't have a hyphen in it.

Comment: if (P.[Name]+' - '+P.[Description]) is NULL then it becomes KanBan. Note: ISNULL(P.[Name]+' - '+P.[Description], 'KanBan') AS Sprint

Comment: try put 'ISNULL(P.[Name]+' - '+P.[Description], 'zzzzzzzz')' instead of 'CASE WHEN (P.[Name]+' - '+P.[Description]) = 'KanBan' then 1 else 0 end' in ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to modify this a bit:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNULL(P.[Name]+' - '+P.[Description], 'KanBan') = 'KanBan'
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END
```

The issue is that you're never getting `KanBan` in your `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I see thanks, how can I override the order of non-'KanBan' sprint cells with the alphabetical order of Product also?

Comment: @DavidTunnell, just adding `Project` after this in the `ORDER BY` clause will do that. It will order by the weight first, then alphabetical.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem a little convoluted but I think it's the most illustrative method:

```
; WITH cte AS (
  <put your query here>
)
SELECT list
     , of
     , columns
     , including
     , the
     , kanban
     , one
FROM   cte
ORDER
    BY CASE WHEN sprint = 'KanBan' THEN 937 ELSE -937 END ASC
     , Product
     , Sprint
     , story
     , task
```